# Org.JSON on Plugin Dependency

Tags: java, json, eclipse-plugin

I noticed that my org.json is on my plugin dependencies.

Plugin dependencies:

[image: plugindependencies]

When I looked into my `pom.xml`, my json is working without the declaration of the json dependency on it.

pom.xml

[image: pom.xml]

I am building a plugin for eclipse.

When they tried to run my project with they get "no class definition" for json exception.

Maybe you have an idea on what's going on?

Comment: it seems my JSONObject is coming from my plugin dependency. how can it be?!

Comment: The Java Build Path is not the plugin's dependencies - those are listed in the MANIFEST.MF as `Require-Bundle` or `Import-Package`. The plugin will **not** be able to find plain Jars unless you include them in the plugin.

Comment: How come does org.json works on my manifest. But not working when my mate tried to do the same? They got Error on bundle for org.json

Comment: There are far too many things that might be wrong to say why it doesn't work for your mate. But you **must** put the dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF and include any extra jars in the plugin.

Comment: The org.json is likely not working for your buddy because the plugin is missing in his eclipse installation or the target platform he has configured. To do things right you guys should be sharing a common target platform that has all the dependencies your plugins require in MANIFEST.MF